# How does a capacitor discharge? Shouldn't the electric field prevent the charges from leaving the plates?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

If the charges on opposite plates of a charged capacitor are attracted to each other by the electric field between them, once we connect the capacitor to a device, how come the charges leave the plates? Shouldn't they remain at the plates since they are still attracted to the charges on the opposite plate? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a **mobile** negative charge in the wire connecting the two plates of the capacitor.
That charge would be in an electric field generated by the positive and negative plates of the capacitor and hence experience a force due to those charges.
That force would cause the negative charge to move towards the positive plate and eventually reach the positive plate, neutralising a positive charge on the positive plate so the positive plate becomes less positive.
The positive plate less positive means that it exerts a smaller force on the negative charges on the negative plate and the negative charges start moving towards the positive plate via the wire.
This movement of mobile charges continues resulting in the the capacitor discharging.

Answer (score 1):

That is true the electric field shall appose discharge, yet when you provide alternative path between capacitor plates then the force of attraction will provide less resistance path for the charge to move to the opposite charge plate.

The medium between opposite charges plates is of very high resistance, so if charged capacitor in closed loop circuit the charges on plate will have alternative path with less resistance to combine with the opposite charge on the opposite plate.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. So basically you mean we typically want to connect a low potential wire to the positively charged plate and a high potential wire to the negatively charged plate so the charges will leave the plates or else it will just keep on charging.

Comment: Both plates have equal potentials. What i mean is when we connect the capacitor to close loop circuit the charges will have new path to opposite plate. Because the medium between the plate is of very high resistance!

Comment: Do you mean for a discharged capacitor?

Comment: For a charged capacitor

Comment: woah I never looked at it that way. So even if the wire is very long, the electric field can travel through the wire and reach the other plate and attract the charges on the other plate. I'm still kind of confused by what you mean by equal potentials on both plates. 
Shouldn't the plates have different potentials since one is positively charged and one is negatively charged?

Comment: We dont talk about potential levels about capacitor, it is charged or discharged of opposing charges and how much voltage

Comment: Oh I see. Can you kindly clarify what you meant before by both plates have equal potential?

Comment: I ment equal potential of opposite charge, one plate is +q, the other plate -q

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Electric field produced by two opposite charges, sitting freely in space. That field extends everywhere outwards from the positive charge, and everywhere inwards from the negative charge. Imagine these two charges are each sitting on a capacitor plate, but we will not think about the plate right now.

The field is directing any other positive charge (some other charge on the plate) to flow away from the original positive charge. If you provide a wire, or some other conductor, it can do so. Likewise, said field lines lead into the negative charge. While they might not line up with the wire perfectly, they would have some component going along the wire in the direction of the negative charge, and that component pushes them.

Charge will therefore flow until the field is neutralised, i.e. all the + and - charges meet, and cancel. Strictly, it is the negative charges which move in a real wire.

At least that's the way I think it is, with a kind of normal force coming from the wire, confining the charges to it.

The real question is this: Suppose I put a positive charge in free space, and another positive charge by it, which is, of course, repelled. But I confine the new charge to a wire. And, that wire extends radially out from the first positive charge for a distance, then bends ninety degrees into a circular arc for a time, then continues radially. That means the part of the wire along the bend is an equipotential. Could any force compel the positive charge to move along the wire at that bend, or would it have to stay in place at the corner, and stop moving away from the original charge because of the equipotential - and does it matter whether, after some meters, the wire continues to move radially outward?